# How to extract data from an irregularly formatted data file in python

Tags: python, parsing

I need to extract certain data from a file, but this file is formatted to be read by humans, and is therefore irregular. First off there is a large amount of text before any of the data actually begins:

> ```
>    DL_POLY Version 2.20
>
>                         Running on   10 nodes
> ```
>
> > ---
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ***************     DLPOLY: LiNbO3                                                                       >***************
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ---
> >
> > ---
>
> SIMULATION CONTROL PARAMETERS
>
> simulation temperature           1.4500E+03
>
> simulation pressure (katm)       0.0000E+00
>
> selected number of timesteps         8000
>
> equilibration period                  500
>
> data printing interval                 80
>
> statistics file interval               80
>
> simulation timestep              5.0000E-04
>
> Nose-Hoover  (Melchionna) isotropic N-P-T 
>   thermostat relaxation time       1.0000E-01
>   barostat relaxation time         5.0000E-01
>
> trajectory file option on
>   trajectory file start                   1
>   trajectory file interval               80
>   trajectory file info key                2
>   ...

Then after a while there is the actual data but it is in this funny form:

> ---
>
> step     eng_tot    temp_tot     eng_cfg     eng_vdw     eng_cou     eng_bnd     >    eng_ang     eng_dih     eng_tet
>   time(ps)      eng_pv    temp_rot     vir_cfg     vir_vdw     vir_cou     vir_bnd     >vir_ang     vir_con     vir_tet
>   cpu  (s)      volume    temp_shl     eng_shl     vir_shl       alpha        beta       >gamma     vir_pmf       press
>
> > ---
> >
> > 1 **-1.1289E+05**  1.4750E+03 -1.1386E+05  1.7276E+04 -1.3114E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >          0.0 -1.1545E+05  0.0000E+00  9.6539E+03 -1.2118E+05  1.3083E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >          0.8  5.3733E+04  1.2367E+02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00 -7.5549E+01
>
> rolling -1.1289E+05  1.4750E+03 -1.1386E+05  1.7276E+04 -1.3114E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>   averages -1.1545E+05  0.0000E+00  9.6539E+03 -1.2118E+05  1.3083E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>             5.3733E+04  1.2367E+02  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00 -7.5549E+01
>
> > ---
> >
> > 80 **-1.1290E+05**  1.5021E+03 -1.1392E+05  2.1894E+04 -1.3726E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >          0.0 -1.1256E+05  0.0000E+00  8.6671E+02 -1.3974E+05  1.3707E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >         10.6  5.3149E+04  1.1377E+03  1.4419E+03  3.5382E+03  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00  1.1119E+01
>
> rolling -1.1290E+05  1.6145E+03 -1.1398E+05  2.0750E+04 -1.3588E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>   averages -1.1333E+05  0.0000E+00  3.3694E+03 -1.3512E+05  1.3565E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>             5.3481E+04  1.0997E+03  1.1430E+03  2.8391E+03  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00 -1.2096E+01
>
> > ---
> >
> > 160 **-1.1287E+05**  1.2629E+03 -1.1376E+05  2.1450E+04 -1.3633E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >          0.1 -1.1249E+05  0.0000E+00  3.8761E+02 -1.3824E+05  1.3612E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >         20.5  5.3375E+04  4.9015E+02  1.1243E+03  2.5052E+03  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00  1.2676E+01
>
> rolling -1.1288E+05  1.4677E+03 -1.1389E+05  2.1589E+04 -1.3663E+05  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>   averages -1.1235E+05  0.0000E+00  2.1147E+02 -1.3884E+05  1.3643E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>             5.3152E+04  7.4818E+02  1.1440E+03  2.6211E+03  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00  1.7174E+01
>
> > ---

On the 9th data interval there is a slight anamoly:

> > ---
>
> switching off temperature scaling at step    500
>
> > ---
> >
> > ```
> >  560 -1.1287E+05  1.4709E+03 -1.1390E+05  2.1600E+04 -1.3678E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> >  0.3 -1.1292E+05  0.0000E+00  1.9253E+03 -1.3743E+05  1.3656E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
> > 68.4  5.4300E+04  1.5043E+02  1.2775E+03  2.7947E+03  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00  2.0576E-01
> > ```
>
> rolling -1.1286E+05  1.4784E+03 -1.1390E+05  2.1546E+04 -1.3673E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>   averages -1.1298E+05  0.0000E+00  2.1361E+03 -1.3717E+05  1.3651E+05  0.0000E+00  >0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
>             5.4303E+04  2.2261E+02  1.2785E+03  2.8027E+03  5.6396E+01  5.6396E+01  >5.6396E+01  0.0000E+00 -1.7421E+00
>
> > ---
>
> ---

As you can see there is a pair of '----' lines which may interfere with proper parsing of the data.

Lets say I want to get just 'the eng_tot' data from this file (the bolded numbers), how would I go about doing that in Python? The number is always in the same place in the file (second quantity, first row after second set of ----s.

By the way the header part with all the definitions in it repeats every 8 steps, execpt the first step in which there are 9 lines. I'd like to just ignore the first step. For now lets say I want to start with line 295 inclusive. Just so you know, I'm quite new to python and programming in general so all the help you can provide is appreciated.

Here's the code I tried, but Eng_Total is still an empty set:

```
import re
import inspect

def lineno():
    """Returns the current line number"""
    linenum = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
infile =  open('FilePath/OUTPUT.01').read()
Eng_Total = []
for line in infile:
#    if 'eng_tot' in line.split(): 
     if re.match("\s+-+\s+", line):
    lineno(line)
        line = linenum+1
        sanitized_line = line[8:]
        eng_total = line.split()[0]
        Eng_Total.append(eng_total)
print Eng_Total
```

Comment: I had fixed your formatting for you.  You don't want the lines prefixed with greater-than.  You want the lines prefixed with four spaces.  Select your text and then click the icon in the toolbar that has 101010 in it.  (Go into the 'edit' view and click the dropdown for "Rev" at the top of the screen, you can see what changes I made.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do this:

- iterate over lines in the output
- search for one containing `eng_tot`:

  - `if 'eng_tot' in line.split(): process_blocks`
- gobble up lines until one matches all dashes (with optional spaces on either side)

  - `if re.match("\s+-+\s+", line): proccess_metrics_block`
- process the first line of metrics:

  - cut the first column off the line (it makes it harder to parse, because it might not be there)

    - `sanitized_line = line[8:]`
    - `eng_total = line.split()[0]` , the first column is now eng_total
- skip lines until you reach another line of dashes, then start again

After seeing your edits:

- You need to import the `re` (regular expression) module, at the top of the file : `import re`
- The `process_blocks` and `process_metrics_block` were pseudo code.  Those don't exist unless you define them. :)  You don't need those functions exactly, you can avoid them using basic looping (`while`) and conditional (`if`) statements.
- You'll have to make sure you understand what you're doing, not just copy from stack overflow! :)

It looks like you're trying to do something like this.  It seems to work, but I'm sure with some effort, you can come up with something nicer:

```
import re

def find_header(lines):
  for (i, line) in enumerate(lines):
    if 'eng_tot' in line.split():
      return i
  return None

def find_next_separator(lines, start):
  for (i, line) in enumerate(lines[start+1:]):
    if re.match("\s*-+\s*", line):
      return i + start + 1
  return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  totals = []
  lines = open('so.txt').readlines()

  header = find_header(lines)
  start = find_next_separator(lines, header+1)

  while True:
    end = find_next_separator(lines, start+1)
    if end is None: break

    # Pull out block, after line of dashes.
    metrics_block = lines[start+1:end]

    # Pull out 2nd column from 1st line of metrics.
    eng_total = metrics_block[0].split()[1]
    totals.append(eng_total)

    start = end

  print totals
```

You can use a generator to be a little more pythonic:

```
def metric_block_iter(lines):
  start = find_next_separator(lines, find_header(lines)+1)
  while True:
    end = find_next_separator(lines, start+1)
    if end is None: break
    yield (start, end)
    start = end


if __name__ == '__main__':
  totals = []
  lines = open('so.txt').readlines()

  for (start, end) in metric_block_iter(lines):
    # Pull out block, after line of dashes.
    metrics_block = lines[start+1:end]

    # Pull out 2nd column from 1st line of metrics.
    eng_total = metrics_block[0].split()[1]
    totals.append(eng_total)

  print totals
```

Comment: Here's the code I came up with, but I keep getting a syntax error when I run it:
infile = OUTPUT
    Eng_Total = []
    for line in OUTPUT:
        if 'eng_tot' in line.split(): process_blocks
        if re.match("\s+-+\s+", line): proccess_metrics_block
         sanitized_line = line[8:]
         eng_total = line.split()[0]
         Eng_Total.append(eng_total)

Comment: Here's the code I came up with, but it keeps giving me a sytax error:
infile = OUTPUT
Eng_Total = []
for line in OUTPUT:
    if 'eng_tot' in line.split(): process_blocks
    if re.match("\s+-+\s+", line): proccess_metrics_block
     sanitized_line = line[8:]
     eng_total = line.split()[0]
     Eng_Total.append(eng_total)

Comment: @Maimon : update your question with the code so you can format it properly.  Comment the code with the places you see syntax errors.

Comment: Well that was kind of my question: how do I process those blocks so that I can get the values I want? Like I said, I'm pretty new to this. I'm still learning the basics and I need this specific piece of code, and not much more.

Comment: For both of these forms I'm getting this error:

eng_total = metrics_block[0].split()[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Maimon : dunno, it worked on my testdata.  Looks like you're going to have to debug.  Try `print metrics_block` to see what it's failing to parse.

Comment: when I run print metrics_block[0] and comment out the last part of the code, I get the first line of data (like I want) but every other line is an empty set. However when I run print metrics_block[0].split()[1] it prints out until the 9th line. I looked back to my previous run with just metrics_block[0], and the 9th line is this: ['\n'].

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to define the file format explicitly, and then you should be able to parse that easily.

The first step is figuring out where the data you need is defined.  Then throw away everything up to that point.  Then start reading.

If the `eng_tot` can move, you need to figure out where in the block of useful data it is.  So, read a line, `entries = line.split(); location = entries.index('eng_tot')`, then read th entry out of that location in the associated line in the output data.

The key is that you need to break down your problem into steps that you know you can do.  When looking at something new it's easy to get overwhelmed.  If you can just start doing *something*, you'll find that you can reach the solution without too much trouble after all.

Comment: The problem is the quantity isn't marked by the string eng_tot. While it is always in the same place relative to that string, I don't know how to access it in that way.